# New Criterion to Carmichael Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, primality-test, pseudoprimes

Can anyone prove the following:

If $p = a\cdot b\cdot c$ is a Carmichael Number and $ m = \operatorname{lcm}((a-1), (b-1), (c-1))$ (least common multiple), prove $(p-1)/m$ is prime. (This applies to Carmichael Numbers with more factors.)

My research efforts show that the proof for this is the basis this [primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_primality_test) (a converse of Fermat's Little Theorem) but how the primality test and/or my claim are related I am not sure. Thanks for helping me on this.

Comment: First one I tried:  $N=10585=5\times 29\times 73$.  $lcm (4,28,72)=504$ and $\frac {10584}{504}=21$.

Comment: Then the primality test (converse of Fermat's Little Theorem) fails for $n = 10585$?

Comment: What do you mean?  The Lucas-Lehmer Test is a theorem (not hard to prove).

Comment: Are $a$, $b$, $c$ primes?

Answer (score 1):

The proposition is wrong, it can be disproved by counter examples:
$$1729 = 7 \cdot 13 \cdot 19$$
$$m = \operatorname{lcm}(6, 12, 18) = 36$$
$$(p - 1) / m = 1728 / 36 = 48$$

$$41041 = 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 41 $$
$$m = \operatorname{lcm}(6, 10, 12, 40) = 120$$
$$(p - 1) / m = 41040 / 120 = 242$$

Other counter examples are 2465, 8911, 15841, 62745 and (infinitely?) many more.